# How to have multiple parameter packs

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Suppose I have a class `List`:

```
template<class... items>
class List;
```

Which is really just a place to stick a large amount of parameters and give it a name.

What I really want is to somehow merge two `List`s together.

An attempt:

```
template<class First,class Second>
struct Merge { };
template<template<class...> class First,template<class...> class Second,class... FirstItems,class... SecondItems>
struct Merge<First<FirstItems...>,Second<SecondItems...> >{
  typedef List<FirstItems...,SecondItems...> value;
};
```

But this fails, because you cannot have two parameter packs into a template.

So how do I do this?

Comment: Apart from the missing `>` before `{`, your code is correct. See [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a5271b48658cc1e).

Comment: @O'Neil Sorry I guess I just assumed that it was not going to work....

Answer (score 2):

When writing code involving templates, make sure to include closing `>` for each opening `<`, or your code will not compile.

You may be tempted to write a regular expression to make sure your code has this property.  Do not: it cannot be done.  A c++ compiler will happily give you an error message about the missing `>`, often in an easy to read "`<` at line 77 was not closed".

Needless to say, your code (once the missing `>` is added), compiles fine.